# Read a File twice with Different Parameters

Tags: hadoop, parameters, mapreduce

I know that you can spawn two mappers of the same file if you type the addinputpath function twice with the same path, but I'd like the file to be processed slightly different each time.

Specifically, I want each time to use different parameters that I passed through the Job class (with configuration.set/get). When the files are different I get the path/name of the file by using the context/inputsplit classes to achieve that, but now that they are the same I can't differentiate them. Any thoughts?

Each mapper is a different maptask but i have no idea if i can use any info regarding the maptasks. Also I don't know the order the framework matches inputsplits to maptasks - it could be useful.

Alternatively I could duplicate the file(using a different name), but that would be a waste of resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to overwrite the inputsplit and inputformat classes (fileinputformat and filesplit for convenience).

I added and extra field in the filesplit to differentiate which time a split is read. It's working great

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to put this logic into your Mapper. It will be more efficient than having Hadoop to scan and process the same file twice.

So pseudo code would be like that:

```
map(key, value, context) {

  //do something with this key/value
  ...
  //emit output 1
  context.write(...)

  //do something else with this the same key/value
  ...
  //emit output 2
  context.write(...)
}
```

If you need your output 1 and 2 to be dispatched to different reducers, you will need to craft your output keys to do so.

Comment: The problem is that the /*do something with this key value*/ costs a lot and thus the emits must happen parallelly. Is there really no other way to differentiate two reads of the same file?

Comment: How about running it in two threads and wait for both to complete? Hadoop may run multiple mappers on a same node anyways, so it does not make much difference really.

Comment: If you think /* do something with this key value */ is costly, run more mappers to achieve best parallelism. Here also, while one mapper is writing output 1 , the other might be writing output2.  Above approach looks best as it avoids IO being done twice which is a great performance booster. Secondly, its not possible to differentiate between 2 files and take in different parameters in same MR job.